# How to create a block for each value in an arraylist in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I want to create a graphic where a rectangle is added for every value in an `ArrayList`. The end result expected is a series of rectangles in the horizontal direction for every value in the `ArrayList`.

I have tried the following code and I get error of `NullPointerException` when I execute the code. Can anyone tell me how to get the output that I expect?

```
import processing.core.*;
public class Processing extends PApplet {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private PApplet parent;

    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    public void setup() {
          size(640, 600);
          background(255);
          test.add(10);
            test.add(20);
            test.add(30);
          noLoop();
        }

        public void draw() {
          for(int testing: test){
              printTask(x,y);
          }
        }

        public void printTask(int x, int y){
            parent.rect(10,10,x,y);
        }
        static public void main(String args[]) {
            PApplet.main(new String[] { "--bgcolor=#ECE9D8", "Processing" });
        }
}
```

Stack trace of exception:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Processing.printTask(Processing.java:30)
  at Processing.draw(Processing.java:25)
  at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1602)
  at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you initializing `parent` anywhere?

Comment: @RobEarl Im new to using processing. I am initializing parent as seen in code...`private PApplet parent;`

Comment: Your Processing Object is already a PApplet, likely you meant `rect(10,10,x,y);` rather than `parent.rect...`

Comment: @RobEarl when I changed from parent.rect to rect..I get one single rectangle as the output..how do I get a series of rectangles like I want?

Comment: The arguments to rect should be: x, y, width, height. Did you want `rect(x, y, 10, 10);`?

Comment: no I am not sure about what metrics I should use to get the rectangle. But I want a series of rectangles one after another for the values in the ArrayList..I am not able to get any help on using ArrayList in Processing though!

Comment: Are you using the Processing PDE?

Comment: @v.k. yes Im using the Processing PDE

Comment: Wait, if this is in the Processing IDE, why are you writing plain java instead of real Processing?

Comment: That's my point, you got a code wrote using Processing as a Java library. I'll post below your code in Processing way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Processing extends PApplet {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    public void setup() {
        size(640, 600);
        background(255);
        test.add(10);
        test.add(20);
        test.add(30);
        noLoop();
    }

    public void draw() {
        for (int testing : test) {
            printTask(x + testing, y);
        }
    }

    public void printTask(int x, int y) {
        rect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--bgcolor=#ECE9D8", "Processing" });

}
```

}

I don't know why you want the parent reference for now.
You've got your x,y order a bit messed up, as people commented already.
Also notice I'm passing calling `printTask` like so:

```
printTask(x + testing, y);
```

If you simply pass x the way as is, all your squares will be drawn in the same position, since x doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

The `parent` variable isn't being initialized anywhere. As `Processing` extends `PApplet` you can get rid of the `parent` variable and change `printTask`:

```
public void printTask(int x, int y){
    rect(x, y, 10, 10);
}
```

You will also need to change draw to use the values from your `List` somehow:

```
public void draw() {
    for(int testing: test){
        printTask(x + testing, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree with this part of the answer. But I seem to be missing something in the logic which gives me only 1 rectangle rather than a series of rectangles. Can you suggest what Im missing there?

Comment: @user2358330, see my edit. You aren't using the values you put into your `ArrayList` at all, only the `x` and `y` ints which don't change.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code could look if wrote in Processing way ;-) As You were not using the values stored in test, I used them for squares sizes... Also I would say that methods should be named in a descriptive way, something like "drawRects()"

[edit] I edited the code to get closer to the description of your goal, I think... :)

```
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

void setup() {
  size(640, 600);
  background(255);
  for (int i = 1; i< 60;i++){
    test.add(i*10);
  }
  noFill();
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  for (int testing: test) {
    printTask(testing,testing);
  }
}

void printTask(int x, int y) {
  rect(x, 10, 10, y);
}
```